# Discord | How do I make it where an avatar command is made it works using ID's not only mentioning

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

As the question says, because I would like to use ID's as well to get someones avatar not only by pinging them.

```html
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name: 'avatar',
    aliases: ["av"],
    run: (bot, messages, args) => {

        let member = messages.mentions.users.first() || messages.author;
        let avatar = member.avatarURL({ format: 'png', size: 4096, dynamic: true});
        

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setImage(avatar)
        .setTitle(member.tag)
        .setDescription(member.id)
        .setFooter("©️ 2021 Yeet Yeet", "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/647213722762215434/776935761807147028/staff_one.jpg")
        .setColor("#FD1C03")

            messages.channel.send(embed);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing with defining a certain variable with different code lines is that it would find the best match for the user's input. So let's take your request - We would first want to check if the first argument was an ID and if it can be turned into a user object. Then, if it can't be turned into a user object, we'd like to look for a user mention inside of the message. If it doesn't exist, then we'll finally result in getting the message author's user object. From that logic, we can simply use:

```
const member = client.users.cache.get(args[0]) || message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
             // checks for ID                   checks for mention                checks for message author
```

#### Final code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'avatar',
    aliases: ["av"],
    run: (bot, messages, args) => {

        let member = client.users.cache.get(args[0]) || messages.mentions.users.first() || messages.author;
        let avatar = member.avatarURL({ format: 'png', size: 4096, dynamic: true});
        

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setImage(avatar)
        .setTitle(member.tag)
        .setDescription(member.id)
        .setFooter("©️ 2021 Yeet Yeet", "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/647213722762215434/776935761807147028/staff_one.jpg")
        .setColor("#FD1C03")

            messages.channel.send(embed);

        }
    }
```